# How position a Multi-currency drop-down in the Supply theme

Tags: css, grid, themes, shopify

I'm having problems positioning the 'Multi-currency form' in the 'Supply' theme.
I've done it before in other themes without trouble, but this time I can't see why it's positioning the drop-down on the left of the container - we need it positioned on the right.

This is how it looks:
[image: snapshot of screen]

This is the relevant portion of the code:
[image: Picture of the code]

I've tried adding all/many of the justify-items: end justify-contents:end options, but I'm obviously missing something critical/simple;?

============================some time later==================================
Well I was missing:

```
.shopify-currency-form {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

But even so, had problems moving it to the right position responsively.

By trial&error I've got this far, but I don't like having to switch to absolute!!
/* added Multi-currency form  */

```
.shopify-currency-form {
  margin-bottom:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
select[name=currency] { 
  width:100px;
  height: 43px;    /*  same as cart button */
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
@media screen and ( max-width:768px ) {   /* move form to bottom right of header */
  .shopify-currency-form {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -16px;
    float: right;
  }
}
@media screen and ( max-width:480px ) {   /* move form up to top right of header */
  .shopify-currency-form {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    top: 53px;
    right: 5px;
  }
}
```

Any improvement much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the frontend store link where'd you implemented this?

Comment: Tks it's      https://teststorex-2.myshopify.com/.     I'm also now trying to put the currency form on/in the responsive navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

After checking your site the only thing you need to do is wrap you forms in a div. Put the currency dropdown form at after the search form. See below code.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <form action="/search" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
      <input type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search all products..." aria-label="Search all products...">
      <button type="submit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
      <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
      </button>
   </form>
   <form method="post" action="/cart/update" id="currency_form" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="shopify-currency-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="currency"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/">
      <select name="currency">
         <option value="CAD">CAD $</option>
         <option value="EUR">EUR €</option>
         <option value="GBP" selected="selected">GBP £</option>
         <option value="USD">USD $</option>
      </select>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  What would we do if we didn't have wrappers ;)